# Flash SWF file cannot find XML data file when loaded into WebBrowser control (but works in IE9)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, webbrowser-control

Bit of a long explanation below, with a hopefully accurate short question summary here:

Can a .NET WebBrowser control (Win7 64-bit, IE9, current Flash 10.3.183.7) load a SWF file into an <object> tag, where the SWF file is in a separate folder that also contains an XML data file in such a way as to have the SWF file load and display the XML data?

**UPDATE**: Added some more information below based on some further experimentation...

Gory detail:

This has plagued me for a couple of days. Consider the following:

`C:\dev\wb.exe` -- program that uses a WebBrowser to show a local SWF file from the disk

`c:\data\mySWF.swf` -- the SWF file I want to play
`c:\data\myData.xml` -- the file with data that mySWF.swf is looking for

`C:\html\index.html` -- HTML file loaded by wb.exe. This file has an <object> tag to set up a Flash ActiveX control playing c:\data\mySWF.swf.

Originally, this started with `swfobject.js` being used, and when I didn't see the results I was expecting, I kept simplifying until I got to the point where I don't have anything but an HTML file with no additional libraries.

If I load the `index.html` into IE9, it works. I see the SWF file playing with the data from the XML file loaded.

When I run wb.exe, it loads the `C:\html\index.html` file, and I see the SWF playing. But the data fields are empty. If I copy the index.html to `C:\data\index.html` and load it into wb.exe, THEN I see my data.

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
* {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
      </style>
</head>
    <body MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" RIGHTMARGIN="0" TOPMARGIN="0" BOTTOMMARGIN="0"> 
        <object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width=100%" height="100%" id='player1' name='player1'> 
            <param name='movie' value='C:\data\mySWF.swf'>
            <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
            <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
            <param name='base' value='C:\data\'>
            <param name='menu' value='false'>
            <param name='quality' value='best'>
            <param name='scale' value='exactfit'>
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `base` parameter seemed to be part of getting this to work, but I'm stymied as to why (or whether) I can get the Flash ActiveX control to work the way I need it to, without having to load an HTML file from the same folder as the SWF file.

UPDATE: If I put the myData.xml file into the C:\html folder, and I load from C:\html\index.html, I get the data values in the SWF. So it seems that the Flash plug-in is using the path of the index.html file, and NOT the base parameter.

UPDATE: We've found out, through more experiementation, that this problem does NOT appear to occur if the SWF file uses Action Script 2 (AS2) for its XML handling (via XML.load()), but a SWF file using Action Script 3 (AS3) (via URLLoader.load()) does NOT work properly. This just gets weirder.

I appreciate your patience if you stuck around this far, and hopefully you might be able to educate me as to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: As default, Flash Player resolves paths in ActionScript relative to the presenting HTML page, not to where the swf files is. Using the base parameter, you can override that, and specify from where to resolve paths in the ActionScript code, so if you point base to the "data" folder, I guess the ActionScript code should use only "myData.xml" as the URL it loads. Also, ActionScript prefers URLs with / as directory delimiters, not \, even in local Windows paths, so you could try changing that. I haven't tried this, but you could try "/data/" for base, where the first / points to a "root", kind of.

Comment: Lars - Thanks for the follow-up. We've tried all that, including various slashes, having a trailing slash or backslash on the base parameter value, and using a file:/// prefix. None of those make a difference. It's seeming to be more and more a WebBrowser problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-up to my own question, there's no nice solution.

We worked around the issue by using jQuery to adjust a `<base href="">`tag in the main HTML to refer to the folder with the SWF and XML file in, each time we loaded a new SWF file. That works, but no one's really happy with it.

We talked to Microsoft, and then to Adobe. Adobe calls the use of Flash in a .NET WebBrowser control an "unsupported use case" and doesn't want anything more to do with the issue.