# Bizarre XML access behavior in .NET WebBrowser between Action Script 2 and Action Script 3

Tags: .net, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, webbrowser-control

I'd started a discussion about a problem with a SWF file not loading an XML data file when rendered in a .NET WebBrowser control (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520433/flash-swf-file-cannot-find-xml-data-file-when-loaded-into-webbrowser-control-but))

Further investigation has revealed that if the XML data file is loaded using Action Script 2 (via XML.load()), it works. But if the SWF file in question uses Action Script 3 (via URLLoader.load(), I think), the data file is NOT loaded, UNLESS the XML file is in the same folder as the HTML file.

If either SWF file is loaded using Internet Explorer 9, then everything works OK.

Are there any know issues (which would be apparently well-hidden from Internet search engines, because we've been beating on those) regarding the performance of SWF + Action Script 3 + .NET WebBrowser?

It's just so weird that there are ways to coerce the AS3 solution to work by moving files (not really an option for what we want to do), and that Internet Explorer 9 has no trouble, but the WebBrowser control (which everyone SAYS "is just a wrapper for IE") does NOT work the same way.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you upgrade to SWFObject and embed that why you wont have these cross browser issues. Well the issues will 99% go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add a wrap-up to the sordid saga...

Through discussions with Microsoft and Adobe, we determined that this was indeed an issue with the Flash ActiveX control being used in a WebBrowser control. Adobe describes this as an "unsupported use case" and that's the end of the story. There's not going to be a "fix". I was able to replicate the issue with the ActiveX WebBrowser control as well, so it's not a .NET thing exclusively. And, as mentioned, the version of ActionScript in use also contributes to success or failure.

What did get done in the long run was to dynamically adjust a `<base>` tag in the overall HTML document during the loading, and pointing the reference to the folder that held the SWF and XML files. Seems kludgy, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it isn't a cross browser problem - SWFObject is not a magic bullet in that regard. We experienced the problem initially while using SWFObject and removed it from the equation to verify that it was specific to the C# WebBrowser control (and not any actual specific browser).

The issue has to do with the passing of BASE parametre information to the C# control. It appears to be successfully passed when run in IE, Firefox and others. It's only in the context of the C# WebBrowser control that this data seems to get lost. And, specifically, only in the case of an AS3 swf as opposed to an AS2 swf. Using the standard load operations for each case, simply reading a file, where the base path is specified in a host HTML page, using the most basic embed method (no special frameworks or APIs), that information (the BASE parameter data) is apparently not received by the Flash in the case of AS3 files. It seems to be consistantly received and processed by the AS2 files and the file is able to be located.

It's quite vexing and it's a little surprising that we haven't been able to find more posts of folks having the problem. In any case, it doesn't seem to be a cross-browser issue, per se. The browsers proper all work as expected vis a vis the BASE parametre. The problem only manifests in this case of using the C# WebBrowser control. It's as if it isn't supporting the newer AS3 engine or something like that.

Anyway, i hope that clears up the issue somewhat...

Comment: Note that the above was not meant as an answer but rather a followup comment to The_asMan and a clarification of the issue GuyWithDogs and i am seeing... thanks!